# Symfony2 bundle specific Twig configuration/variables

Tags: symfony

I know that I can set Twig variables in my `app/config/config.yml`, however I want to set variables on a per bundle level (eg: `Bundle/Resources/config/??.yml`).

For example I want to include a bundle version identifier in the footer of my pages.  I tried placing twig config into my bundles' `services.yml` however Symfony wasn't able to parse the configuration.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could implement bundle specific configs for your example. The configs in bundles tend to be imported into the main config files which are now environment specific rather than bundle specific.

However, for your example I would just make a twig extension which returns the name of the bundle you're using. That way you can use it wherever you like in your templates. You can get the fully named route of your controller from the request, then just use preg matching to get the Bundle name. Something like the below should work:

```
public function getBundleName()
{
    $pattern = "#([a-zA-Z]*)Bundle#";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($pattern, $this->container->get('request')->get('_controller'), $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

In this example `$this->container` has been set in the constructor to be an instance of the container. If you are using another method to get the controller then substitute accordingly.